Want to use two instances of Objectmapper, one to use for custom masking logging, other to be used for api response
Want to use two instances of Objectmapper, one to use for custom masking logging, other to be used for api response..
Basically, I want masking in logs, which should be annotation based on properties, but it shouldn't reflect api response.
If I am using @JsonSerialization annotation, my API response is getting serialized, but I want to use that only for logging purpose
